# optimize cascade jointure QueryBuilder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4, query-builder

I have a QueryBuilder query, working, but pretty greedy. I'd like to know if I could optimize it.

Here is my entity setup :
I have n (a dozen) Project (p), having n (can be thousands) medias (m), having 1 transcription (t), having n (can be thousands) transcription logs (l).

I'd like to retrieve all projects, sorted by its last transcription log (the createdAt property). I guess there some ways to optimize it but I can't figure out my own.

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
          ->select('p')
          ->leftJoin('p.medias', 'm')
          ->leftJoin('m.transcription', 't')
          ->leftJoin('t.transcriptionLogs', 'l')
          ->andWhere('p.archived = 0')
          ->addOrderBy('l.createdAt', 'DESC')
          ->addOrderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
          ->getQuery()
          ->getResult();
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you are questionning the Query itself, I don't see how you could even more optimize it.

But, you can optimize the way it is used by the rest of you code. You can do so by adding some `SELECT` to the query. This way, when you will loop around your data in the Controller or in Twig, Doctrine will have a grouped query rather than multiple queries.

This is how you can achieve this :

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p') 
      ->leftJoin('p.medias', 'm')

      // Joining the transcription and adding the select
      ->leftJoin('m.transcription', 't')
      ->addSelect('t')

      // And doing the same for the logs
      ->leftJoin('t.transcriptionLogs', 'l')
      ->addSelect('l')

      ->andWhere('p.archived = 0')
      ->addOrderBy('l.createdAt', 'DESC')
      ->addOrderBy('p.id', 'DESC')
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult()
;
```